# Are Expression Blend 4 and Blend for Visual Studio 2012 same?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend-4

I want to make an online simulation for physics and chemistry. So, that everyone would be able to run this simulation in browser. What do you suggest me to use. And also tell me the Difference between Expression Blend 4 and Blend for Visual Studio 2012. I have visited Microsoft website but could not find a satisfied answer. 
<<>>

Answer (score 0):

From Visual Studio 2012 Microsoft had made Expression Blend available as a part of Visual Studio and not as a separate package as was before.

Expression Blend 4 supports Silverlight 4 and WPF 4 and is also compatible with Silverlight 3 and WPF 3.5 SP1.

If you are trying to build Silverlight Applications, you can try using Blend for Visual Studio 2012/2013 as its the latest available application with latest framework - allowing you to use recent APIs.

Comment: but brother when I open blend only two types of projects can be created as the welcome screen shows HTML project or XAML project.

Which one is used for Silverlight Application. 

do I need some extra Plugins or Addons.?

Comment: It may be because you are using Expression Edition of Visual Studio for Windows 8.  Trying using Professional Edition ;-) Cheers.